# How do I set height WRAP_CONTENT in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So I know that when **I don't use Modifier.height()** is like "WRAP_CONTENT" is set, but what if I want to set the value in height as WRAP_CONTENT. Is there a way to do this?

Already tried InstrinsicSize.Min, InstrinsicSize.Max and 0.dp.

Looking for something like this: `Modifier.height(WRAP_CONTENT)`

This is just for specific knowledge as I can't find nothing in the documents.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `wrapContentHeight` modifier.

For example:

```
Box(
    Modifier.size(50.dp)
        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        .height(20.dp)
        .background(Color.Blue)
)
```

In this case the result will be a `50.dp` x `20.dp` blue box centered vertically in a `50.dp` x `50.dp`
if `wrapContentHeight` did not exist, the blue rectangle would actually be `50.dp` x `50.dp` to satisfy the size set by the modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use it as **Modifier.wrapContentWidth()** or **Modifier.wrapContentHeight()** or both as:

```
Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.happy_meal_small),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth().Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
)
```

which works as WRAP_CONTENT